# Search an Array with nested arrays and return

Tags: php, arrays

The Array format

```
Array
(
[76ea881ebe188f1a7e7451a9d7f17ada] => Array
    (
        [rowid] => 76ea881ebe188f1a7e7451a9d7f17ada
        [id] => 1
        [qty] => 2
        [price] => 20
        [name] => First
        [options] => Array
            (
                [permName] => beer
            )

        [subtotal] => 40
    )

[e7a36fadf2410205f0768da1b61156d9] => Array
    (
        [rowid] => e7a36fadf2410205f0768da1b61156d9
        [id] => 3
        [qty] => 6
        [price] => 20
        [name] => Second
        [options] => Array
            (
                [permName] => achieve
            )

        [subtotal] => 120
    )
```

Is there a way for me to search this array for the title or in this case lets say `e7a36fadf2410205f0768da1b61156d9` and once it is found just return the `price` and the `qty` values?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you array_key_exists function to check if there is any element with a given key.

```
$title = 'e7a36fadf2410205f0768da1b61156d9';   
if (array_key_exists($title, $arr)) {
    return array('price'=>$arr[$title]['price'], 'qty'=>$arr[$title]['qty']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$title = 'e7a36fadf2410205f0768da1b61156d9';

if (isset($arr[$title])) {
    return array('price'=>$arr[$title]['price'], 'qty'=>$arr[$title]['qty']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function is enough.

```
function search_title($title, $array){
    if(array_key_exists($array[$title])){
        return array($array[$title]['price'],$array[$title]['qty']);
    }else{
        return array( false, false);
    }
}
```

Usage,

```
list ($price, $qty) = search_title('e7a36fadf2410205f0768da1b61156d9', $array);

if($price!==false){
    // search was successful
}
```